# MySQL Procedure problems in the tables

Tags: mysql

I have this code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE inserting(IN rowcount INT)
BEGIN
    declare i int;
    declare codigo int;
    declare nombre varchar(30);
    declare apellido varchar(30);
    declare fecha date;
    declare sexo boolean;
    declare sueldo float;
    SET i = 0;
    SET codigo = (SELECT MAX(codigo)+1 FROM trabajador);
    WHILE i < rowcount
    DO
        SET nombre = CONCAT('nombre', codigo);
        SET apellido = CONCAT('apellido', codigo);
        SET fecha = DATE_ADD('2000-01-01', INTERVAL (RAND()*15*365) DAY);
        SET sexo = FLOOR(RAND() * 2);
        SET sueldo = 500.0 + RAND() * 4500.0;
        INSERT INTO trabajador(codigo, nombre, apellido, fecha, sexo, sueldo) 
            VALUES (codigo, nombre, apellido, fecha, sexo, sueldo);
        SET i = i + 1;
        SET codigo = codigo + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And I got this:

```
+--------+--------+----------+------------+------+---------+
| codigo | nombre | apellido | fecha      | sexo | sueldo  |
+--------+--------+----------+------------+------+---------+
|   NULL | NULL   | NULL     | 2001-03-07 |    0 | 2750.63 |
|   NULL | NULL   | NULL     | 2000-11-19 |    1 | 4084.73 |
|   NULL | NULL   | NULL     | 2008-12-22 |    1 | 1511.38 |
|   NULL | NULL   | NULL     | 2004-08-30 |    1 | 2622.88 |
|   NULL | NULL   | NULL     | 2010-09-24 |    0 | 3522.82 |
|   NULL | NULL   | NULL     | 2012-12-31 |    0 | 507.951 |
|   NULL | NULL   | NULL     | 2000-09-14 |    0 | 519.938 |
|   NULL | NULL   | NULL     | 2005-01-09 |    1 | 1880.39 |
|   NULL | NULL   | NULL     | 2008-03-11 |    1 | 2392.52 |
|   NULL | NULL   | NULL     | 2009-12-30 |    0 | 2131.24 |
+--------+--------+----------+------------+------+---------+
```

But the NULL is wrong...it has to be in the first row, something like this:

```
1    nombre1   apellido1
```

what is wrongs about the Procedure?

someone can help me, please?

Comment: no need for all of those `sets`. just `declare` your variables once up the top, without the `@` and then access them via name, without the `set`

Comment: @pala_ I get this error:  decla' at line 1

Comment: by up the top, i mean, after `begin`

Comment: `create or replace` isnt mysql syntax. change it to just `create`

Comment: @pala_ Still I getting an error:   declare i' at line 1

Comment: the variable declaration is the wrong way around in the parenthesis. it is `name type` not `type name`. you also need to give a type to the variables you declare, ie `declare i integer;`

Comment: @pala_ Sorry... but:    declare i intege' at line 1

Comment: Change integer to int

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE inserting(IN rowcount INT)
BEGIN
    declare i int;
    declare codigo int;
    declare nombre varchar(30);
    declare apellido varchar(30);
    declare fecha date;
    declare sexo boolean;
    declare sueldo float;
    SET i = 0;
    SET codigo = (SELECT MAX(codigo)+1 FROM trabajador);
    WHILE i < rowcount
    DO
        SET nombre = CONCAT('nombre', codigo);
        SET apellido = CONCAT('apellido', codigo);
        SET fecha = DATE_ADD('2000-01-01', INTERVAL (RAND()*15*365) DAY);
        SET sexo = FLOOR(RAND() * 2);
        SET sueldo = 500.0 + RAND() * 4500.0;
        INSERT INTO trabajador(codigo, nombre, apellido, fecha, sexo, sueldo) 
            VALUES (codigo, nombre, apellido, fecha, sexo, sueldo);
        SET i = i + 1;
        SET codigo = codigo + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You need to declare the type of parameters in the prototype of the procedure. Meaning, whether the variable is IN, or OUT or INOUT. If the procedure returns a value then it must be declared as OUT otherwise IN (for referring in the procedure). If it is used and the same variable value is returned, then we need to use INOUT.

Comment: I get this:   declare i int' at line 1

Comment: Can you post an image or the log as such @NataliTorres

Comment: Thanks but now, I have another problem :(

Comment: @NataliTorres what is that? Post the exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76116/discussion-between-java-enthusiast-and-natali-torres).